# The differences between the return times to a recurrent state of a discrete Markov chain are independent and identically distributed

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

Let

- $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$ be a measurable space and $\mathbb F=(\mathcal F_n)_{n\in\mathbb N_0}$ be a filtration on $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$
- $E$ be an at most countable set equipped with the discrete topology
- $X=(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb N_0}$ be a discrete Markov chain on $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$ with respect to $\mathbb F$ with values in $(E,\mathcal E)$

> Let $x\in E$ be recurrent, $$\tau_x^k:=\inf\left\{n>\tau_x^{k-1}:X_n=x\right\}\;\;\;\text{with }\tau_x^0:=0\;,$$ $t_0:=x$ and $$t_k:=\tau_x^k-\tau_x^{k-1}\;\;\;$$ for $k\in\mathbb N$. How can we prove, that $(t_k)_{k\in\mathbb N_0}$ is independent and identically distributed with respect to $\operatorname P_x$?

---

Let $k\in\mathbb N_0$. Then, $\tau:=\tau_x^{k-1}$ is a $\mathbb F$-stopping time. Let $$\tilde X:=\left(X_{\tau+n}\right)_{n\in\mathbb N_0}\;.$$ The strong Markov property yields for all $n\in\mathbb N_0$
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\operatorname P_x\left[t_k=n\right]&=\operatorname P_x\left[\tilde X_1\ne x,\ldots,\tilde X_{n-1}\ne x\text{ and }\tilde X_n=x\right]\\
&=\operatorname P_{X_\tau}\left[X_1\ne x,\ldots,X_{n-1}\ne x\text{ and }X_n=x\right]\\
&=\operatorname P_x\left[X_1\ne x,\ldots,X_{n-1}\ne x\text{ and }X_n=x\right]
\end{split}\tag 1
\end{equation}
$\operatorname P_x$-almost surely, since $\operatorname P_x\left[\tau<\infty\right]=1$ by the recurrence of $x$. Since the right-hand side of $(1)$ doesn't depend on $k$, the $t_k$ are indeed identically distributed.

How can we show, that they are independent, too?

Comment: Strong Markov property again. $t_{1},\dots,t_{k-1}$ are $\mathcal F_\tau$-measurable, but $t_k$ is independent of $\mathcal F_\tau$.

Comment: @zhoraster Why is $t_k$ independent of $\mathcal F_\tau$?

Comment: You wrote this. $P_x(t_k = n|\mathcal F_\tau) = P_x(t_k = n|X_\tau) = P_{X_\tau}(t_1 = n) = P_x(t_1 = n)$.

Comment: @zhoraster Yes, you're right. Actually, $(1)$ should be $$\text P_x\left[t_k=n\mid\mathcal F_\tau\right]=\text P_x\left[t_1=n\right]\;\;\;\text P_x\text{-almost surely}$$ for all $n\in\mathbb N_0$. Thus, $$\text P_x\left[t_1=n_1,\ldots,t_k=n_k\right]=\text E_x\left[\text P_x\left[t_1=n_1,\ldots,t_k=n_k\mid\mathcal F_\tau\right]\right]=\text E_x\left[\prod_{i=1}^{k-1}1_{\left\{t_i=n_i\right\}}\text P_x\left[t_k=n_k\mid\mathcal F_\tau\right]\right]=\text P_x\left[t_1=n_k\right]\text P_x\left[t_1=n_1,\ldots,t_{k-1}=n_{k-1}\right]=\cdots=\prod_{i=1}^k\text P_x[t_1=n_i]$$

Comment: @zhoraster Correct?

Comment: Looks correct to me.